# при отправке формы через submit происходит переход на скрипт не указанный в action. Скрипт, на который перешли, не видит $_POST

Tags: php

```
<form method="post">
    <input class="input" name="login" placeholder="Логин" required="required"><br>
    <input class="input" type="password" name="password" required="required" placeholder="Пароль"><br>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="sub" value="Войти">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    echo "Кнопка";
    require_once "../connectdatebase.php";

    $query="SELECT * FROM autorizathion";
    $result = $mysql->query($query) or die("Ошибка " .mysqli_connect_error());
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pas = $_POST['password'];
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {       
        if ($login == $row['login'] && $pas == $row['password'])
          { 
           header("Location: adminpanel.php");
          } 
    }
}
else{
    echo "Кнопка не нажата";
}
?>
```

При отправке формы происходит такой переход
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первоначально было так:

`<form method="post" action="adminavt.php">`

Потом action удалила, но переход, КАКИМ-ТО образом, остался.
Я уже с ума от этого схожу(
 Как он остается? Где хранится? Где этот переход прописан?

По большому счету, обработка формы и была запланирована в этом файле, но почему "adminavt.php" считает, что форма не была отправлена (сообщение: "кнопка не нажата", массив $_POST пустой)

Наверное, у меня какая-то ОЧЕНЬ тупая ошибка. Помогите, пожалуйста!!!!
Сейчас файл формы такой:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Страница</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="adminStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form">
            <div class="p">
                <p>АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ!!!!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="div-input">
                <form method="post" action="adminavt.php">
                    <input class="input" name="login" placeholder="Логин" required="required"><br>
                    <input class="input" type="password" name="password" required="required" placeholder="Пароль"><br>
                    <input class="button" type="submit" name="sub" value="Войти">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="div">
                <a href="writePasswordAdmin.php" class="a">Изменить</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Файл "adminavt.php" такой:

```
<?php ob_start();
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_POST);
    if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
        echo "Кнопка";
        require_once "../connectdatebase.php";
        $query="SELECT * FROM autorizathion";
        $result = $mysql->query($query) or die("Ошибка " .mysqli_connect_error());

        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $pas = $_POST['password'];

        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            if ($login == $row['login'] && $pas == $row['password'])
            {
                header("Location: adminpanel.php");
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Кнопка не нажата";
    }
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Результат тот же: 
сообщение: "кнопка не нажата", массив $_POST пустой

Comment: Если `action` нет, то запрос отправляется по текущему адресу

Comment: Я в курсе(
Но здесь не отправляется( Именно это и выводит меня из терпения(

Comment: всё нормально отрабатывает. и в первом случае, и во втором.

Comment: чисто за для успокоения души, добавьте форме атрибут enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: это же учебный таск, не боевой, надеюсь :)?

Comment: Конечно же нет) Я понимаю, что это ужас ужасный)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Консоль разработчика в браузере с отметкой "сохранять лог" и логи на веб-сервере.
Чудес не бывает, где-то происходит редирект.

Предположу что с adminpanel.php идет идет редирект на adminavt.php

Но, по-хорошему, конечно, за такой скрипт авторизации ремня бы надо и двойку в четверти.